# Magento Replace bundle product price with new base price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, bundled-product

I am building a magento store for gaming pcs,where the PC is a bundled product, Now i need to keep the base price i.e. "Initial price of the product" to be a defined amount by admin and NOT the sum of the default options, and when the customer selects any option from the product page, than the price should be calculated acording to the base price.

Thanks.

Comment: And how would that work exactly? Is the base price not part of the options? What does this base price represent and what stock mutations should be done for that?

Comment: @Melvyn The base price is an attribute, that is supposed to be inserted by admin, Example: If i have a bundle product,that has a final price $540, ad the and the base price set by admin is $599, than, in the front end, the price should be $599 with default bundle options selected, and if the customer changes the options than **the price changes need to be done on the base price and not on the default price**. Line $599 + $40 and not $540+$40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not logical to have a bundle item with fixed price and keeping child product with their default price. Magento is not written on that logic because when you want to apply discount, it will get messed up.

However, you can get it done with little tweak, which needs you to enter prices of each child product manually.

**Choose Price as Fixed while creating bundle product and then you can add child product's price manually.**

So if you set a bundle's price (initial) as $100 and each child product's price $10, $20 $30 etc, then when user chooses each option on front end system will keep adding these child product's prices.

Remember, this approach is not the best practice, because when a child product's prices changes then you have to come to bundle product and change manually one by one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reqired option with only one selection, call it something like "Base" or "Core" and set it to your desired base price (or to base price minus sum of default options).

If you want, you can then use some template tweaking and hide this option from the product page. That's a simpler and less error-prone modification than anything that messes with Magentos price calculations.

Comment: But the problem is that we need to display this price to category page, include in the cart subtotal,and everywhere else.

Comment: It will be used everywhere because you are using the standard features. That's the beauty of the solution.